# Unsigned integer and unsigned char holding same value yet behaving differently why?

Tags: c

Why is it so that

```
unsigned char k=-1
if(k==-1)
```

is false

```
unsigned int k=-1
if(k==-1)
```

is true

Comment: `unsigned` stands for `>=0`

Comment: It compiles, but Dev-C++ said: `[Warning] comparison is always false due to limited range of data type`

Comment: u should be printing value before being quite sure what value it holds and how is value stored

Comment: me using codeblocks it uses Gcc i guess

Comment: @AnkitBanerjee You're aware that they probably *aren't* holding the same value, right?

Comment: @undefined behavior:yep i jst understood my mistake....

Answer (score 19):

For the purpose of demonstration let's assume 8-bit `char`s and 32-bit `int`s.

```
unsigned char k=-1;
```

`k` is assigned the value 255.

```
if(k==-1)
```

The left-hand side of the `==` operator is an `unsigned char`. The right-hand side is an `int`. Since all possible values of an `unsigned char` can fit inside an `int`, the left-hand side is converted to an `int` (this is performed due the the integer promotions, quoted below). This results in the comparison `(255 == -1)`, which is false.

---

```
unsigned int k=-1
```

`k` is assigned the value 4294967295

```
if(k==-1)
```

This time, the left-hand side (an unsigned int) cannot fit within an int. The standard says that in this case, both values are converted to an unsigned int. So this results in the comparison `(4294967295 == 4294967295)`, which is true.

---

The relevant quotes from the standard:

Integer promotions: (C99, 6.3.1.1p2)

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

Usual arithmetic conversions: (6.3.1.8).

> [For integral operands, ] the integer promotions are performed on both operands.  Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   ...
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>   ...

Comment: maybe you could leave a quote of the standards 6.3.1.3.

Comment: I added the standard quotes related to promotions and conversions, which are the core issue here. 6.3.1.3 Describes what happens when converting from signed to unsigned which is also relevant, but I think what the exact rule is is less important here so I won't quote it.

Answer (score 1):

§6.3.1.1p2 of the C11 standard draft (n1570.pdf):

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions.58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

In your second case, an int can't represent `unsigned int k` because that's out of range. Both operands end up being converted to `unsigned int` and compare equal.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no sign extension in unsigned promotion the result is defferent.

`unsigned char k` is promoted from unsigned char (value=255) to int (value=255).

In the case of `unsigned int k`, -1 is promoted from int (value=-1) to unsigned int (value=2^32-1).

Comment: No, `unsigned int` is never promoted to `int`. It's the `int` that is converted to `unsigned int` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char k = -1;
```

-1 is an integer literal of type `int`, which is equivalent to `signed int`. When you assign a large signed integer to a smaller unsigned type, the result will get truncated in undefined ways, the C standard does not guarantee what will happen.

In the real world outside the C standard, this is what's most likely (assuming 32-bit CPU, two's complement):

-1 is 0xFFFFFFFF. The least significant byte of 0xFFFFFFFF will get assigned to `k`. `k == 255`. Try to print it using `printf("%u")` and see for yourself.

In the case of `unsigned int k=-1`, -1 is still a signed int. But it gets implicitly (silently) promoted to an unsigned int when it is stored in `k`. When you later compare `k == -1`, the right side -1 will once more get promoted to an unsigned type, and will compare equal with the data stored in `k`.

Comment: According to the C standard, "the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
until the value is in the range of the new type."