# Compiler code generation comparisons

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

Ok, so all started here: [Unsigned integer and unsigned char holding same value yet behaving differently why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771890/unsigned-integer-and-unsigned-char-holding-same-value-yet-behaving-differently-w)

I wrote the following application to understand what happens behind the scenes (ie, how the compiler is handling this issue).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  {
  unsigned char k=-1;
  if(k==-1)
  {
    puts("uc ok\n");
  }
  }

  {
  unsigned int k=-1;
  if(k==-1)
  {
    puts("ui ok");
  }
  }
}
```

And while compiling it with GCC like:

```
gcc -O0 -S -masm=intel h.c
```

I get the following assembly file:

```
    .file   "h.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section        .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "ui ok"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov     rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], -1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], -1
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], -1
    jne     .L3
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    puts
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And to my big surprise the first check is NOT EVEN THERE.

But, if I compile the same thing with Microsoft Visual C++ (2010), I get (I have cut off a lot of garbage from this listing, that's why it's not so valid):

```
00B81780  push        ebp  
00B81781  mov         ebp,esp  
00B81783  sub         esp,0D8h  
00B81789  push        ebx  
00B8178A  push        esi  
00B8178B  push        edi  
00B8178C  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00B81792  mov         ecx,36h  
00B81797  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00B8179C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00B8179E  mov         byte ptr [k],0FFh  
00B817A2  movzx       eax,byte ptr [k]  
00B817A6  cmp         eax,0FFFFFFFFh  
00B817A9  jne         wmain+42h (0B817C2h)  
00B817AB  mov         esi,esp  
00B817AD  push        offset string "uc ok\n" (0B857A8h)  
00B817B2  call        dword ptr [__imp__puts (0B882ACh)]  
00B817B8  add         esp,4  
00B817BB  cmp         esi,esp  
00B817BD  call        @ILT+435(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0B811B8h)  
00B817C2  mov         dword ptr [k],0FFFFFFFFh  
00B817C9  cmp         dword ptr [k],0FFFFFFFFh  
00B817CD  jne         wmain+66h (0B817E6h)  
00B817CF  mov         esi,esp  
00B817D1  push        offset string "ui ok" (0B857A0h)  
00B817D6  call        dword ptr [__imp__puts (0B882ACh)]  
00B817DC  add         esp,4  
00B817DF  cmp         esi,esp  
00B817E1  call        @ILT+435(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0B811B8h)
```

The question is: Why is this happening? Why does GCC "skip" the first IF and how can I force GCC to not to skip it? Optimizations are disabled, but it seems it still optimizes away something ...

Comment: Because 1. the `-O0` flag doesn't *actually* turn off all optimizations, 2. the optimizer of GCC is smarter than that of MSVC.

Comment: @H2CO3 then how do I turn off ALL the optimizations? even the ones from static analysis? :)

Comment: do you get the same results if you use -O0 and if you dont set a -O on the command line at all?

Answer (score 7):

My guess (I'm not a GCC developer) is that it does enough static analysis to prove to itself that the first `if`'s test is never true.

This shouldn't be **too** hard, since there is no code between the initialization and the test, there is no way any side-effect or external entity could change the variable.

Just for curiosity, try making the variable `static` and/or `volatile` to see if anything changes.

Comment: Marking it volatile should work. If not, declare an int, then a volatile pointer to it, then update the value through the volatile pointer.

Comment: Specifying static or volatile actually made the "missing code" to appear :) nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem with GCC, although admittedly a very minor one.

From [GCC's documentation website](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) (emphasis mine):

> Without any optimization option, the compiler's goal is to reduce the cost of compilation and to make debugging produce the expected results. **Statements are independent**: if you stop the program with a breakpoint between statements, you can then assign a new value to any variable or change the program counter to any other statement in the function and get exactly the results you expect from the source code.

So with `-O0` you should be able to place a breakpoint between `unsigned char k=-1;` and `if(k==-1)`, during that breakpoint modify `k`, and expect the branch to be taken; but that is not possible with the emitted code.

Comment: The OP specified `-O0`, which *is* an optimization option, no?

Comment: @OwenWengerd I considered that at first and tried to peer into the document to understand it better. I think the key is that `-O0` is the default, that's what applies if no other option is used - so there's no way to not supply any optimization option, and I think this is what the documentation means by "without any optimization option".

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** My guess is that the char, as a type below the base (int) type, is simply upscaled to the integer type for the comparison. (assuming the compiler took the literal as integer, and generally prefers word sized integers over byte sized ones)

And as an unsigned value, zero extension is always positive  (note the **MOVZX** instead of the signed variant!), so the check was optimized away by basic constant propagation probably.

You could try to force the literal to be a byte (cast or suffixes), e.g. comparing with ((unsigned char)(-1)) and maybe then the compiler will insert an 1-byte comparison, and the result might be different.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of fine points here:

- The Compiler does not even have to look at the initialization of k to prove that the condition k==-1 can never be true in the unsigned char case. The point is, that the **unsigned** 8 bit value needs to be promoted to 32 bits, because the right hand side of the comparison is an integer constant, which is by default 32 bits. Because k is unsigned, the result of this promotion will be `00000000 00000000 00000000 xxxxxxxx`. The constant -1 has the bit pattern `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`, so it does not matter what `xxxxxxxx` is, the result of the comparison will always be false.
- I might be wrong on this point, but I believe that even if k was specified as volatile, the compiler would only be required to load it into a register (because the load operation might trigger some desired side effect in the hardware), not to actually perform the comparison or produce code for the unreachable if-block.
- Actually, omiting producing assembly for unreachable code is entirely in accordance with the goal of -O0 to speed up the compilation process.
- AFAIK, the comparison between an unsigned and a negative constant is undefined behaviour anyway. At the very least, there is simply no machine instruction to correctly handle the case, and compilers won't insert the necessary code to handle it in software as you can see from the disassembly. All you get is an implicit cast between signed and unsigned that results in an integer overflow (which is undefined behaviour in itself), and a comparison of unmixed sign.